# Passing a temporary file to Popen subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, subprocess, temporary-files

I am trying to pass a temporary file to another python file and print the results of the second python file. I notice, however - i'm not gettin anything back from the other file. Is it possible to pass temporary files to subprocesses?

When I try reading from the tmp file I can see values are being written to it, but it appears that it is not being received by the other file. in the other file I've simply written (t = input(), for var in t: print(t))

[Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ75A.png)

tmp file gen code:

```
for block in input_list: #iterating through blocklist
    # open the file here
    f = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+')
    
    for val in block: #write to the file
        f.write(val)
        #print(val)
    f.seek(0)
    #print(f.read())
    user_code= subprocess.Popen(['python', 'test_code.py'], stdin=f, stdout=PIPE)
    user_code.wait()
    mssg = user_code.communicate()
    print(mssg)
    print(mssg[0].decode('utf-8').strip())
```

Comment: `input()` reads until a newline, does `block` contain any newlines?

Comment: Yep, so block tends to look something like this: ['\n','1','2,'\n', '3',\n']. I'll attach an image of what I get when I print from the tmp file

Comment: `(t = input(), for var in t: print(t))` doesn't look like valid Python code, you can't have a `for` loop inside a tuple.

Comment: I see what you're saying - what would be the proper way to read from the file then? I tried changing it to t = input(), print(t)  -- but still get nothing from the 2nd python file. Also wondering if you just can't pass tmp files that way

Comment: Those should be separate lines in `test_code.py`.

Comment: I'm king of the idiots - I was definitely screwing up the second file. Used import sys and read from stdin and it works. Thanks for your help!